# How to add additional params to a button_to form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to have a `Submit` button. It updates one field on the submission; `submission.state = :submitted`

Now, I could make a custom route and a custom action and just post to that. But that seems really heavy-handed. Especially since I'll also have a `reject` button and possibly more. Needing a custom route & action for each of those seems downright silly to me.

It would be much nicer if I could do something like

```
button_to "Submit", submission_url(submission), :method => :put, :submission => { :state => :submitted }
```

Which would post to the submission's `update` method and update only the desired field.

But that doesn't work. How can I make it work? Or do you have a better idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10471) mentioned by @AugustinRiedinger has been merged and is now available as of **Rails 4.1.0**. Now just add the `params` option:

```
params: { state: :submitted }
```

Comment: Note that the params option currently don't allow nested hashes. Example: `params: {user: {active: false}}` is not allowed. You can bypass this using the ugly`params: {:"user[active]" => true}`

Comment: I'm on Rails 5.2.1 and there is now support for nested hashes.

Answer (score 12):

It's not as concise, but without extending Rails, this will get me by:

```
= form_for submission, :html => { :class => "button_to" } do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :state, :value => :submitted
    = f.submit "Submit", :class => "link"
```

Comment: So there is no other solution? Like a `button_to "Submit", submission_url(submission), :method => :put, :params => {:submission => { :state => :submitted }}`

Comment: Apparently this evolution has been developped, but needs to be integrated still: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10471

Answer (score 11):

Add params:{} at the end, it will generate hidden_field

```
<%= button_to user.name, user, class:"btn btn-default", style:"", method: :patch, remote: true, params: { a_field: false, an_other_field:"a new value" } %>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have something similar that works:

`button_to "Submit", submission_url(submission, :submission => { :state => :submitted }), :method => :put`

Comment: This works, but it appends the params to the query string which seems a bit ugly.

Answer (score 3):

So, as from this rails pull request : https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10471

Here is what you can do to have your custom button_to.

In `application_helper.rb`, add these lines:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  // Unfortunately these 2 methods need to be redefined. I don't know how I could access the original ones.
  def token_tag(token=nil)
    if token != false && protect_against_forgery?
      token ||= form_authenticity_token
      tag(:input, type: "hidden", name: request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, value: token)
    else
      ''
    end
  end

  def method_tag(method)
    tag('input', type: 'hidden', name: '_method', value: method.to_s)
  end

  def button_to_with_params(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    html_options, options = options, name if block_given?
    options      ||= {}
    html_options ||= {}

    html_options = html_options.stringify_keys
    convert_boolean_attributes!(html_options, %w(disabled))

    url    = options.is_a?(String) ? options : url_for(options)
    remote = html_options.delete('remote')
    params = html_options.delete('params') { Hash.new }

    method     = html_options.delete('method').to_s
    method_tag = %w{patch put delete}.include?(method) ? method_tag(method) : ''.html_safe

    form_method  = method == 'get' ? 'get' : 'post'
    form_options = html_options.delete('form') || {}
    form_options[:class] ||= html_options.delete('form_class') || 'button_to'
    form_options.merge!(method: form_method, action: url)
    form_options.merge!("data-remote" => "true") if remote

    request_token_tag = form_method == 'post' ? token_tag : ''

    html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)
    html_options['type'] = 'submit'

    button = if block_given?
      content_tag('button', html_options, &block)
    else
      html_options['value'] = name || url
      tag('input', html_options)
    end

    inner_tags = method_tag.safe_concat(button).safe_concat(request_token_tag)
    params.each do |name, value|
      inner_tags.safe_concat tag(:input, type: "hidden", name: name, value: value.to_param)
    end
    content_tag('form', content_tag('div', inner_tags), form_options)
  end
end
```

And to use it:

```
= button_to_with_params 'Awesome button', awesome_action_path, method: :put, :params => {:my_param => 'my_value'}
```

Enjoy! Have fun Railing!

Comment: I'm the author of that PR. It was accepted into Rails so the `params` option is now available since Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

If I read things correctly what you are effectively wanting to do something specific when a standard rails form is submitted in the standard way.

Notice that when a form is submitted using e.g.

`f.submit "Save Changes"`

then

`params[:commit] = "Save Changes"`

The GOOD thing about this is that it can allow you to do some appropriate branching in the controllers update action.

The BAD thing is that it's brittle.  If one day you or someone else decides to change the button text, things break.. which is bad.

K

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 3.2.1 you can add additional params to the :html_options hash using the :form key.

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

This did not exist prior to 3.2.1 so the more verbose solution of declaring a form with hidden attributes was required.

Comment: :html_options does not let you add hidden input elements to the form that button_to creates. It will add options to the html of the input tag. There is, however, one option you can pass to html_options that will generate a hidden field in the form and that is the method option. See the documentation for examples: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to