# How to submit a form with button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to submit and save some data. I need some post IDs from a form:

```
def message_post_collection_params
    params.require(:message_post).permit(
      { post_ids: [] }
    )
end
```

How can I take the IDs by button_to? My code:

```
button_to('Submit', approve_collection_message_posts_path, params: { message_post: { post_ids: ['1', '2'] } }, data: { config: 'Are you sure?', remote: true })
```

But it thows an error:

```
undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x007ffbdf9f1540>
```

on line params.require(:message_post).permit(.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Would help to show the console request with sent params

Answer (score 0):

The reason I down voted Mike K's answer is because the declaration of the params does not appear to be the issue:

[image]

I believe the issue will be in how you're assigning `params` in the `button_to`:

```
button_to 'Submit', approve_collection_message_posts_path, params: { message_post: { post_ids: ['1', '2'] } }, data: { config: 'Are you sure?', remote: true }
```

[image]

Notice: `<input type="hidden" name="message_post" value="post_ids%5B%5D=1&amp;post_ids%5B%5D=2" />`

This is why you're getting your error (there is no nesting in your array) -- your params literally look like: `"message_post" => "post_ids%5B%5D=1&amp;post_ids%5B%5D=2"`

---

## Fix

There is a cheap way to fix it:

```
def message_post_collection_params
   params.permit(post_ids:[])
end

= button_to 'Submit',  path_helper, params: { post_ids: ["1","2"] }, data: { config: 'Are you sure?', remote: true }
```

[image]

--

If you wanted to retain your nesting, you could use the [following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886963/how-to-add-additional-params-to-a-button-to-form#comment-41278736):

> Note that the params option currently don't allow nested hashes.
>   Example: `params: {user: {active: false}}` is not allowed. You can
>   bypass this using the uglyparams: `{:"user[active]" => true}`

```
params: {:"message_post[post_ids]" => ["1","2"]}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This should work:
`{ :message_post => { post_ids: ['1', '2'] } }`

Here's an example of it in rails console:

```
2.2.3 :017 > params = { :message_post => { post_ids: ['1', '2'] } }
 => {:message_post=>{:post_ids=>["1", "2"]}} 
2.2.3 :018 > parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)
 => {"message_post"=>{"post_ids"=>["1", "2"]}} 
2.2.3 :019 > parameters.require(:message_post).permit(
2.2.3 :020 > { post_ids: [] })
 => {"post_ids"=>["1", "2"]}
```